# How do I add AppBar with Back to Top button from Material UI for React in my App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, appbar

In the documentation of Material UI, I found this code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import useScrollTrigger from '@material-ui/core/useScrollTrigger';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp';
import Zoom from '@material-ui/core/Zoom';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        position: 'fixed',
        bottom: theme.spacing(2),
        right: theme.spacing(2),
    },
}));

function ScrollTop(children) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        target: window ? window() : undefined,
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 100
    });

    const handleClick = (event) => {
        const anchor = (event.target.ownerDocument || document).querySelector('#back-to-top-anchor');
        if (anchor) {
            anchor.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
        }
    };
    return (<Zoom in={trigger}>
        <div onClick={handleClick} role="presetation" className={classes.root}>
            {children}
        </div>
    </Zoom>);
}
export default function BackToTop(children) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <AppBar>
                <Toolbar>
                    <Typography variant="h6">Scroll to see button</Typography>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Toolbar id="back-to-top-anchor" />
            <Container>
                <Box my={2}>
                    {[...new Array(100)]
                        .map(
                            () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
                                    Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
                                    Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
                                    Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`,
                        )
                        .join('\n')}
                </Box>
            </Container>
            <ScrollTop {...children}>
                <Fab color="secondary" size="small" aria-label="scroll back to top">
                    <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
                </Fab>
            </ScrollTop>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

There was said that this code is top bar, which will draw  `Back to top` button. But I don't understand what should I pass as `children` to `BackToTop` function. Can anyone help me?
P.S Code also includes content, that is stored inside `Box` element, it is just for testing. If I understand purpose of `children` parameter  right, I should have ability to make `BackToTop` function independent of any parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The portion of the documentation you are referring to is here: https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#back-to-top. The code sandbox version of that demo is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/r59zg?file=/demo.js.

The code in your question has some problematic changes compared to the demo from the documentation. Confusingly, you have renamed `props` to `children` in a couple places (`BackToTop` argument and `ScrollTop` argument). One thing to note in the code from the documentation is that the props passed to `BackToTop` are never used -- they are passed through to `ScrollTop` via `<ScrollTop {...props}>`, but `ScrollTop` doesn't use any of those props either (and since `index.js` doesn't pass any props to `BackToTop`, it is an empty object so there isn't much that **could** be done with it).

Here is a slightly simplified version of the demo to remove the props that aren't used:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import useScrollTrigger from "@material-ui/core/useScrollTrigger";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Fab from "@material-ui/core/Fab";
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from "@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp";
import Zoom from "@material-ui/core/Zoom";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: theme.spacing(2),
    right: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

function ScrollTop(props) {
  const { children } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 100
  });

  const handleClick = event => {
    const anchor = (event.target.ownerDocument || document).querySelector(
      "#back-to-top-anchor"
    );

    if (anchor) {
      anchor.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "center" });
    }
  };

  return (
    <Zoom in={trigger}>
      <div onClick={handleClick} role="presentation" className={classes.root}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </Zoom>
  );
}

ScrollTop.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired
};

export default function BackToTop() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6">Scroll to see button</Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Toolbar id="back-to-top-anchor" />
      <Container>
        <Box my={2}>
          {[...new Array(25)]
            .map(
              () => `Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.
Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.
Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.`
            )
            .join("\n")}
        </Box>
      </Container>
      <ScrollTop>
        <Fab color="secondary" size="small" aria-label="scroll back to top">
          <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
        </Fab>
      </ScrollTop>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Back to top]

The `children` being used in `ScrollTop` are the child elements in the JSX within the `ScrollTop` element. In this case that is:

```
        <Fab color="secondary" size="small" aria-label="scroll back to top">
          <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
        </Fab>
```

This is passing a floating-action-button to `ScrollTop` as the thing to show when the user scrolls and the thing that, when clicked on, will cause the page to scroll back to the top.

The code in your question has `ScrollTop(children)` though instead of `ScrollTop({children})` -- i.e. you are calling the entire `props` object `children` rather than getting the `children` prop out of it.